# React-native keyboard

Tags: react-native, textinput

When the texInput is focused in react-native then my header goes of the screen as the keyboard is opened. I cannot make the changes in android manifest.xml keyboardSoftINputMode to adjustResize. Because if i make it to adjustResize then the keyboardAwareScrollView does not work.

Please suggest me a way so that when my TextInput is focused then my header does not get off the screen. This is occurring in react-native.

Comment: Have you tried using `KeyboardAvoidingView`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [KeyboardAvoidingView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview) to automatically resize your visible area when a TextInput is highlighted.

Usage: Simply wrap your top-level `<View>` or other component in your `App`'s `render()` function with a `<KeyboardAvoidingView>`:

```
import {KeyboardAvoidingView} from 'react-native';

...
<KeyboardAvoidingView>
  ... your UI ...
</KeyboardAvoidingView>;
```

Comment: Yes i have tried that but still the result is same . It is not working.

Comment: Please show us your code so we know what you are trying

Comment: render() {
    const { styles } = this.state
    const style = this.props.testType === 'practice' ? styles.containerStyleCPP : styles.container
    return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior={'padding'}>
      <ScrollView style={style}>
        {this.renderQuestionBasedOnType()}
        {/* <TestEngineNumericalQuestionComponent markAnswer={markAnswer}/> */}
      </ScrollView>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    )
  }
}

const getStyle = () => StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    height: heightPercentage(100)
  }
})

Answer (score 0):

render() {
    const { styles } = this.state
    const style = this.props.testType === 'practice' ? styles.containerStyleCPP : styles.container
    return (
    
      
        {this.renderQuestionBasedOnType()}
        {/*  */}
      
      
    )
  }
}

const getStyle = () => StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    height: heightPercentage(100)
  },
  containerStyleCPP: {
    width: widthPercentage(100)
  }
})

This is my code